# Line fading when drawing swift

Tags: swift4

UPDATE: This does not happen if I set only the board as the main view. Why would this happen when it is a subview?

I have a view that has a game board that you draw over to select characters. To do this I put a UIImageView over the game board and draw the line in touches moved using a helper function. It works, however, while drawing the line, everything that came before it slowly fades and also moves upwards.
It looks like this:
[image]

This is what the draw function looks like and it is called in touches moved:

```
//Helper function that draws a line which is used while the user is selecting letters
func drawLine(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size)

    //get a context
    guard let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
        print("failed to get image context to draw line")
        return
    }

    self.drawingView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

    //set the line
    context.move(to: fromPoint)
    context.addLine(to: toPoint)

    //customize line
    context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context.setLineWidth(4)
    context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
    context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

    //draw the line
    context.strokePath()

    drawingView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    //close
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //print("Drew Line")
}
```

Heres all the code for the view:

```
    /**
 GameControllerDelegate is used to communicate when the user has chosen a word
 */
protocol GameControllerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func wordPicked(letters: [String], moves: [(row: Int, column: Int)])
}

/**
 GameViewDelegate is used to let the gameview know a user has picked a word using the board which is a subview
 */
protocol GameViewDelegate: AnyObject {
    func wordPickedInBoard(letters: [String], moves: [(row: Int, column: Int)])
}



/**
 Game view class holds all the subviews of the Game view as well as provides
 getters and setters for each important data
 */
class GameView: UIView , GameViewDelegate{
    //the board part
    let boardView: BoardView = {
        let boardView = BoardView()
        boardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        boardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        return boardView
    }()
    //the score part
    let scoreView: ScoreView = {
        let scoreView = ScoreView()
        scoreView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        scoreView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        return scoreView
    }()

    //two other vairables to assist in sizing the subviews
    var minusTop: CGFloat = 0
    var minusBottom: CGFloat = 0

    //the board for the game
    var board: [[String]] {
        set
        {
            boardView.boardStrings = newValue
            boardView.generateLabels()
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
        get { return boardView.boardStrings }
    }

    //the score
    var score: Int {
        set
        {
            scoreView.gameScore.text = "  Score: " + String(newValue)

        }
        get
        {
            let indexStartOfNumber = scoreView.gameScore.text!.index((scoreView.gameScore.text!.startIndex), offsetBy: 9)
            let numString = scoreView.gameScore.text?[indexStartOfNumber...]

            return Int(String(describing: numString))!
        }
    }

    //delegate for alerting the controller that a word was picked
    var delegate: GameControllerDelegate? = nil

    init(frame: CGRect, minusTop: CGFloat, minusBottom: CGFloat){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        boardView.delegate = self

        self.minusTop = minusTop
        self.minusBottom = minusBottom 

        addSubview(boardView)
        addSubview(scoreView)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        boardView.delegate = self

        addSubview(boardView)
        addSubview(scoreView)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("It's Apple. What did you expect?")
    }

    //manually layout the alarmpreview
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        var cursor: CGPoint = .zero
        let scoreViewHeight = bounds.height/10
        let boardHeight = bounds.height - minusTop - minusBottom - scoreViewHeight

        cursor.y += minusTop

        boardView.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: bounds.width, height: boardHeight)

        cursor.y += boardHeight

        scoreView.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: bounds.width, height: scoreViewHeight)
    }

    //function to catch when a word is picked in the board
    func wordPickedInBoard(letters: [String], moves: [(row: Int, column: Int)]) {
        //forward the info via the delegate
        delegate?.wordPicked(letters: letters, moves: moves)
    }
}

/**
 Score view shows the users current score
 */
class ScoreView: UIView {
    /*var scoreTitle: UILabel = {
        let scoreTitle = UILabel()

        scoreTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        scoreTitle.text = "Score: "

        return scoreTitle
    }()*/
    var gameScore: UILabel = {
        let gameScore = UILabel()

        gameScore.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        gameScore.text = "  Score: 0"

        return gameScore
    }()

    //init
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(gameScore)
        //addSubview(scoreTitle)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("It's Apple. What did you expect?")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        let cursor: CGPoint = .zero

        gameScore.frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height)
    }
}

/**
 VoardView holds all the cells of the board and communicates when a user draws on it
 */
class BoardView: UIView {
    var drawingView: UIImageView = {
        let drawingView = UIImageView()
        drawingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.0)
        return drawingView
    }()

    //delegate to communicate with the superview
    var delegate: GameViewDelegate? = nil

    //variables to aid in tracking the user moves
    var lastPoint = CGPoint.zero
    var looped = false
    var boardStrings:[[String]] = []
    var board:[[UILabel]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: UILabel(), count: 9), count: 12)
    var curMoves: [(row: Int, column: Int)] = []
    var highlightedArea: [(row: Int, column: Int)] = []

    //centralized colors
    let unHighlightedColor = UIColor.lightGray
    let highlightedColor = UIColor.yellow

    //Initialize this view
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        initBoard()
        //self.boardStrings = generateBoard()
        //generateLabels(boardStrings: self.boardStrings)
        for i in 0...11 {
            for j in 0...8 {
                addSubview(board[i][j])
            }
        }

        addSubview(drawingView)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("It's Apple. What did you expect?")
    }

    //override the draw function, we draw the grid as well as the letters here
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        guard let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            print("failed to attain draw context")
            return
        }

        //8 verticle lines
        for i in 1 ... 9 {
            let fromPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width * CGFloat(Double(i) * 1.0/9.0), y: 0)
            let toPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width * CGFloat(Double(i) * 1.0/9.0), y: bounds.height)
            context.move(to: fromPoint)
            context.addLine(to: toPoint)
            context.strokePath()
        }


        //draw 11 horizontal lines
        for i in 1 ... 12 {
            let fromPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height * CGFloat(Double(i) * 1.0/12.0))
            let toPoint = CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height * CGFloat(Double(i) * 1.0/12.0))
            context.move(to: fromPoint)
            context.addLine(to: toPoint)
            context.strokePath()
        }

    }

    //here we manually layout all the subviews that go into the preview
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        var cursor: CGPoint = .zero
        let width = bounds.width/9
        let height = bounds.height/12

        for i in 0 ... 11 {
            for j in 0 ... 8 {
                board[i][j].frame = CGRect(x: cursor.x, y: cursor.y, width: width, height: height)
                cursor.x += bounds.width * 1.0/9.0
            }
            cursor.x = 0
            cursor.y +=  bounds.height * 1.0/12.0
        }

        drawingView.frame = self.bounds
    }

    //handle the beginning of a user move
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {
        looped = false
        if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
            lastPoint = touch.location(in: self)

            //find what row we are in
            let buttonHeight = bounds.height/12
            let buttonWidth = bounds.width/9

            let row: Int = Int(lastPoint.y/buttonHeight)
            let column: Int = Int(lastPoint.x/buttonWidth)

            curMoves.append((row: row, column: column))
            highlightLabel(row: row, column: column)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    //handle when the user is moving. Calculate coordintes to drive the move the player is making
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {
        if !looped {
            if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {
                let currentPoint = touch.location(in: self)
                drawLine(fromPoint: lastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)

                //find what row we are in
                let buttonHeight = bounds.height/12
                let buttonWidth = bounds.width/9

                let row: Int = Int(lastPoint.y/buttonHeight)
                let column: Int = Int(lastPoint.x/buttonWidth)

                if curMoves[curMoves.count - 1] != (row: row, column: column) {
                    //if the user is backstepping
                    if curMoves.count > 1 {
                        if curMoves[curMoves.count - 2] == (row: row, column: column) {
                            let pos = curMoves.remove(at: curMoves.count - 1)
                            unHeighlightLabel(row: pos.row, column: pos.column)
                        }
                        //if the user tried to make a loop
                        else if curMoves.contains(where: {$0 == (row: row, column: column)}){
                            for pos in curMoves {
                                unHeighlightLabel(row: pos.row, column: pos.column)
                            }
                            print("User tried to make a loop")
                            looped = true
                        }
                        else {
                            curMoves.append((row: row, column: column))
                            if board[row][column].backgroundColor != UIColor.green{
                                highlightLabel(row: row, column: column)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    //if the user tried to make a loop
                    /*else if curMoves.contains(where: {$0 == (row: row, column: column)}){
                        for pos in curMoves {
                            unHeighlightLabel(row: pos.row, column: pos.column)
                        }
                        print("User tried to make a loop")
                        looped = true
                    }*/
                    else {
                        curMoves.append((row: row, column: column))
                        if board[row][column].backgroundColor != UIColor.green{
                            highlightLabel(row: row, column: column)
                        }
                    }
                }

                lastPoint = currentPoint
            }
        }
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    //handle the end of a player move
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with: UIEvent?) {
        if !looped {
            //derive word
            var word: [String] = []
            for move in curMoves {
                //if it contains blank put some garbage in there
                if !boardStrings[move.row][move.column].contains("Blank") {
                    word.append(board[move.row][move.column].text!)
                }
                else {
                    word.append("###")
                }
            }

            //let superview know
            delegate?.wordPickedInBoard(letters: word, moves: curMoves)
        }
        //reset
        for move in curMoves {
            if board[move.row][move.column].backgroundColor != UIColor.green{
                unHeighlightLabel(row: move.row, column: move.column)
            }
        }
        curMoves = []
        looped = false
        drawingView.image = nil
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    //Helper functions that changes the background color of the specified label to a centralized color
    func highlightLabel(row: Int, column: Int){
        board[row][column].backgroundColor = highlightedColor
    }
    func unHeighlightLabel(row: Int, column: Int) {
        board[row][column].backgroundColor = unHighlightedColor
    }

    //Helper function that draws a line which is used while the user is selecting letters
    func drawLine(fromPoint: CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(drawingView.frame.size)

        //get a context
        guard let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            print("failed to get image context to draw line")
            return
        }

        self.drawingView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height))

        //set the line
        context.move(to: fromPoint)
        context.addLine(to: toPoint)

        //customize line
        context.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
        context.setLineWidth(4)
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

        //draw the line
        context.strokePath()

        drawingView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        //close
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        //print("Drew Line")
    }

    //helper function that initilizes the board layout
    func initBoard() {
        for i in 0 ... 11 {
            for j in 0 ... 8 {
                board[i][j] = UILabel()
                board[i][j].text = ""
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     This function takes the generated board strings and converts them into their proper labels
     */
    func generateLabels() {
        highlightedArea = []
        for i in 0 ... 11 {
            for j in 0 ... 8 {
                //board[i][j] = UILabel()
                board[i][j].textAlignment = .center
                board[i][j].layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
                board[i][j].layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

                if boardStrings[i][j].hasSuffix("^") {//.characters.contains("^"){
                    //highlight the label
                    board[i][j].backgroundColor = UIColor.green

                    //set the text
                    let index = boardStrings[i][j].index(boardStrings[i][j].startIndex, offsetBy: boardStrings[i][j].count - 1)
                    let range = boardStrings[i][j].startIndex..<index
                    let letter = String(boardStrings[i][j][range])
                    board[i][j].backgroundColor = UIColor.green
                    board[i][j].text = letter

                    highlightedArea.append((row: i, column: j))
                }
                else if boardStrings[i][j] != "Blank" {
                    board[i][j].backgroundColor = unHighlightedColor
                    board[i][j].text = boardStrings[i][j]
                }
                else {
                    //leave it blank
                    board[i][j].backgroundColor = unHighlightedColor
                    board[i][j].text = ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently experienced the same problem. It might be too late to help you out, but hopefully someone finds this useful someday.

Using floor() for height and width when setting the image view's bounds(image view you want to draw into) worked for me. Did this in objective C... don't know the floor() equivalent for swift.